# What am I missing regarding the toUpperCase method?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, uppercase

I am trying to make the first letter of each word capitalized via `toUpperCase` method and the rest of the word is in the lower case via the `toLowerCase` method. But I am missing something... Why `temp` value is not matching with `result[1][0]` even if I am using that method for both?

Note: I know about other ways (`map`, `replace`, etc) for my solution, but I want to just use a for-loop with `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` methods.

```js
    function titleCase(str) {
  let regex = /[^0-9\s]+/g;
  var result = str.match(regex);
  let temp = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        result[1][0] = result[1][0].toUpperCase();
        temp = result[1][0].toUpperCase();
    }
  }

  console.log(temp); // Output is 'A'
  console.log(result[1][0]); //Output is 'a'
  // Normally 'temp' and 'result[1][0]' should be equal, but one returns a lowercase character and the other an uppercase character.
  return str;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with the `toUppercase()`, it is with the reference.

When referencing `result[1][0]`, why are you including the 0?  You already have the second character with `result[1]`

`result[1]` === 'a'.  No need to include the [0] as well.

Change your code so it looks like this:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    let regex = /[^0-9\s]+/g;
    var result = str.match(regex);
    let temp = "";
    
    result[1] = result[1].toUpperCase();
    temp = result[1].toUpperCase();
  
    console.log(temp); // Output is 'A'
    console.log(result[1]); //Output is also 'A'
    // both now equals capital A
    return str;
  }
  
  titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

**EDIT**:
Updating the function to uppercase the first letter of the word.

We can use ES6, which would make this really simple:

```
const capitalize = (string = '') => [...string].map((char, index) => index ? char : char.toUpperCase()).join('')
```

Use it: `capitalize("hello")` returns 'Hello'.

First we convert the string to an array, using the spread operator, to get each char individually as a string.  Then we map each character to get the index to apply the uppercase to it.  Index true means not equal 0, so (!index) is the first character.  We then apply the uppercase function to it and then return the string.

---

If you want a more object oriented approach, we can do something like this:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(allWords) {
    return (allWords) ?
    this.split(' ').map(word => word.capitalize()).join(' ') : 
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}
```

Use it: `"hello, world!".capitalize();` returns "Hello, World"

We break down the phrase to words and then recursive calls until capitalising all words.  If allWords is undefined, capitalise only the first word meaning the first character of the whole string.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I was removed the for-loop from the code then I forgot it remove it. I have just edited the post. Can you check, please again

Comment: I am sorry, I am having a difficult time understanding your code.   What is it supposed to do?  Why are you doing 2 for loops, but hard coding the values inside of them?  For that reason, my answer will stay the same, even inside the for loop

Comment: I am using two loops because I need to make the rest of the word is in lower case.

Comment: No need to use 2 loops.  I am updating my answer

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer,But , I know the other ways(Map ,replace...) for my solution. But , I want to use just for-loop with toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() methods...

Answer (score 0):

I was tried to change a specific character in the string but strings are immutable in JS so this does not make sense.